# SQL count with sum

Tags: sql, count, sum

[image]

How do I sum up the sales column

```
select 
    count(pp.product_id) as sales,
    so.order_date,
    product_name,
    pp.product_id 
from 
    sales.orders so, 
    sales.order_items oi, 
    production.products pp 
where 
    so.order_id = oi.order_id 
    and pp.product_id = oi.product_id 
    and (order_date >= '01.01.2016 ' and order_date <= '01.31.2016')
    and (pp.product_id = 3 or 
         pp.product_id = 6 or 
         pp.product_id = 9 or 
         pp.product_id = 12) 
group by 
    product_name,
    pp.product_id,
    so.order_date 
order by 
    pp.product_id asc
```

Comment: Side notes: typo? `'01.01.2016 '` the *trailing space* in not expected here. `and pp.product_id in (3, 6, 9, 12)` is a shorter version

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged